# SAPUI5 upload file and use it as model

Tags: file-upload, sapui5, jquery-file-upload

I would like to upload a xml file from the local workspace and use it as model. I can upload files to the server but i don't know how to retrieve the data from the uploaded object and set or load it to my model

Here is how I m uploading the file.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
                url: oFileUploader.getUploadUrl(),
                headers: oHeaders,
                type: 'PUT',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: file
            }); 

        }
```

I could not use the standard oFileUploader.upload() because it uses the http method "POST" and I wanted to do a "PUT"

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how you get the contents of the `file` variable that you are passing to the jQuery.ajax call. Depending on this, you have three options hat come to mind:

1. Directly use the `file` variable contents in a model.
2. Use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read the file contents and put them in a model.
3. Make the back-end service return the XML content of the file as a response to the AJAX call and then store the response in a model.

Comment: thank you. I will give the 2. and 3. a try. I already tried the 1. but "file" is not the xml document itself.

Comment: achieved what  I wanted with the third option. Thank you